What if my question with many details is a duplicate of an existing much simpler question?
I have a fairly technical question (regarding whether a particular C++
program is valid according to the standard).  I have done quite a bit of
research to try to answer it on my own, and while that has exposed a
couple possible angles of attack, and I've collected some related
interpretations, that research hasn't led me to a definitive conclusion.
So I would like to ask my question on Stack Overflow.
But, during my research, I came across an existing question that is
fundamentally asking about the same issue.  However:

It does not have any research, just an example and some speculation.

It is not a bad question.  It merely lacks the additional research.

It is fairly old, having been asked 11 years ago.

The asker was last active on SO 3 years ago.

It has no answers.

It has no upvotes, downvotes, or comments.  Correction: It has three comments; I misremembered that detail when originally asking.

The question I would like to ask (and have already drafted) is around
five times larger (1000 words versus 200).  (As a quick comparison,
this meta question is around 800 words.)


I'd like to know how to proceed.  The available options seem to be:

Ask a new question (while linking to the old).  But them I'm asking
what I already know to be a dup.  If my question receives an answer,
the old one could be closed as a dup of mine, but does that possiblity
excuse asking the dup in the first place?

Edit the existing question.  This is what most of the advice from
questions similar to this one says to do.  But those questions (linked
below) pertain to situations that are materially different.  Moreover,
I'd be adding a great deal of material, putting words into the OP's
mouth that they probably wouldn't disagree with but still aren't
theirs.  How would I title my additions, "Additional research by a
passer-by"?  This seems to lead to attribution problems.  I could flag
it after(?) editing for a moderator to turn it into a community wiki
but I do not know if that is appropriate.

Answer the existing question with my incomplete research effort.
It would at best be a partial answer, but really it is primarily a
question (albeit an elaboration of the original) sitting in the answer
section.  That could create difficulties with further interactions, as
potential answers to my question appear to be answering the original
(and are to an extent, but also mine).

Place a bounty.  I think that action, alone, would not be productive.
I think having the additional research makes reaching a conclusion
significantly more likely.  For example, it could be that someone
merely needs to point out one rule in the standard that, in
combination with the others I've found, answers it.  That isn't
likely with the existing question since a potential answerer has to
start from scratch.


The related existing meta questions I found, along with the reasons I
think they do not clearly apply in boldface, are:

The meta SO question
What can you do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?
points to, in this situation:

the meta SE question
How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?,
but the existing question isn't mine, so it's not clear how
literally to take the advice (which is to edit).

The meta SO question
How to ask same question again on Stack Overflow?
concerns questions that already have answers.

The meta SO question
Is it appropriate to ask a new question if a duplicate already exist?
matches my situation pretty well.  The answer advises to edit the new
information in to the existing question, but "without changing the
intention of question".  I'm concerned about satisfying that
constraint, as that question seemed to suppose the
additional material was not large compared to the existing
question.

The meta SO question
Is there a good way to intentionally ask a duplicate question?
has a firm "No" answer, but the primary suggested alternative is to
place a bounty, which like I say I believe would be
ineffective in this case.

The meta SO question
What if my (duplicate) question is seemingly much better worded than the origin?
ironically complains about an existing question that has too much
detail, but in any case, the advice seems (?) to be to just
post the duplicate and allow it to be closed as such, which is not
a desirable outcome here, although that answer was written after the
deed was done.


What is the recommended course of action here?

You say the duplicate target has no answers, in that case you should simply go ahead and ask your question. We can't vote to close as duplicate if the target doesn't have any answers (with some exceptions that don't apply here). If your question does get answers vote to close the other as a duplicate of yours.

related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/608272

These kind of meta posts are a symptom in itself. You really were doubting to commit a quality question to the repository? That really makes me feel sad. We have legions of people who can't give a crap about quality and just dump any question they want on their personal help desk, and then we have people who do care who feel like they have to ask for permission like this :/ The world upside down.

This confusion can be summarized by the vast majority of the community it understanding that a question can only be a duplicate of another question if the answer to that other question answers the question. In other words a duplicate question is about the answer it necessarily the question that was previously asked. It’s entirely up to you if you want to ask a new question and then answer it yourself or answer the existing question that might be lower quality than the question you would have asked.

"The question I would like to ask (and have already drafted) is around five times larger (1000 words versus 200)." It's not clear to me why you expect that using that many words to ask fundamentally the same question would improve it. While your research may have lead you to approaches that you haven't been able to turn into an answer, that doesn't mean you should lay them out in the question. It means you should write a question where it's already inherently clear why those approaches won't work (if you've already determined that), or just let others show you how to take them (otherwise).

The important questions here are: why do you consider that the existing question is "fundamentally about the same issue"? And, given that it is, what is gained by showing a more complex example of the same issue?

At any rate, I would advise you to aim for few enough words that typical users won't have to scroll the screen in order to see the entire question - unless you need a code example of more than a few lines to actually demonstrate the problem, in which case you might take a bit more.

@KarlKnechtel I have now asked my question.  Perhaps seeing what I have written will explicate why I think the additional details are helpful.  And of course you can comment there about what I should have left out.

Three answers thus far... quite the success I would say.
